# Как перенести отсортированные данные из двумерного массива в одномерный?

Tags: java, алгоритм, junit

На курсе дали задачу написать программу, которая построчно переносит n количество отсортированных по возрастанию чисел из двумерного массива в одномерный.

При этом стоят условия:

1) нельзя использовать System.arraycopy()

2) не должно быть метода public static void main(String[] args) (ибо проверяться все должно автоматическими тестами JUnit)

3) В программе не должно быть ввода и вывода данных

Третий день пытаюсь разобраться, перерыл все что смог найти в гугле, получилось вот это:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
public class Convert2DArrayTo1DArray {

public int[] multiple(int size) {
    int[][] old = new int[size][size];
    int m = old[0].length;
    int[] current = new int[m];
     for (int i = 0; i < old.length; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < old[i].length; j++) {
            old[i][j] = current[i];
        }
    return current;

}
```

Естественно должным образом не работает

Так же есть косячный тест:

```
import org.junit.Test;
import static org.hamcrest.core.Is.is;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertThat;

public class  Convert2DArrayTo1DArrayTest {
    @Test
    public void when2on2() {
        Convert2DArrayTo1DArray convert = new Convert2DArrayTo1DArray();
        int[][] old = Convert2DArrayTo1DArray.multiple(2);
        int[][] input = new int[][] {
            {1, 2},
            {3, 4},
        };
        int result = convert.multiple(input);
        int[] expect = {1, 2, 3, 4};
        assertThat(convert, is(expect));
    }
}
```

Есть варианты как решить эту задачу?

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете эту задачу решить в три строчки с помощью `Stream API`:

```
    int[][] input = new int[][]{
            {1, 2},
            {3, 4},
    };

    int[] result = Arrays.stream(input)
            .flatMapToInt(Arrays::stream)
            .toArray();

    int[] expect = {1, 2, 3, 4};

    assertArrayEquals(expect, result);
```